# Unable to use TestDriven.Net with MSpec

Tags: c#, mspec, testdriven.net

I am currently trying to use TestDriven.Net with MSpec. I installed TestDriven.Net and then imported MSpec from Nuget into my class library. When I try to run my tests I get the following output.

> The target type doesn't contain tests from a known test framework or a
>   'Main' method.

I have also copied the Machine.Specifications.dll.tdnet and Machine.Specifications.TDNetRunner.dll in the Debug folder of my solution where all the dlls are deployed but still I see no change.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Currently, I have this problem and I understand that because I've installed the latest version of NUnit (3.0.5813.39032), TestDriven.Net (TestDriven.NET-3.9.2905 ) doesn't still support this version of NUnit. I'm able to run each test individually but not when I target a class or a namespace. The solution for me is to downgrade my version of NUnit to 2.6 or less.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the TestDriven.Net batch file installer first. It's shipped with the Nuget package. You can find it under

```
\packages\Machine.Specifications.0.8.3\tools\InstallTDNetRunner.bat
```

Comment: I tried but it's still the same. It gives me the message

The target type doesn't contain tests from a known test framework or a 'Main' method.

Comment: Do your specs work as expected when you run them with the MSpec command line runner?

Comment: Yeah if I use the MSpec Test Runner Console all is working fine.

Comment: How are you running the tests? Right-clicking in the file? Or from Solution Explorer? There have been [some issues](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications/issues/85) in the past.

Comment: For me both options are not working whether I run it from Solution Explorer or by right clicking the file.

Comment: Which versions of Visual Studio, MSpec and TestDriven.NET? Make sure you are on the most recent TestDriven. See [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11458895/1077279) where someone was having the same problem but with NUnit.